# jQuery validation plugin. errorLabelContainer does not work after post back

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, postback

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin. I have my form on the master page, i set up my validation rules in one of my aspx pages like this:

```
$("#aspnetForm").validate({

            errorLabelContainer: $("ul", $('div.error-container')),
            wrapper: 'li',

            onkeyup: false,

            rules: {
                ctl00$Content$dbTurnOverDate$txtDate: {
                    dateISO: true,
                    required: true,

                },
                ctl00$Content$nbAmount$txtNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                },
                ctl00$Content$dbPeriodicityStart$txtDate: {
                    dateISO: true
                },
                ctl00$Content$dbPeriodicityStop$txtDate: {
                    dateISO: true
                },
                ctl00$Content$ccTurnoverCategory$txtCategory: {
                    required: true
                }


            }, messages: 
                {
                    ctl00$Content$dbTurnOverDate$txtDate:{required: 'Date is required', dateISO: 'Date must be ISO'},
                    ctl00$Content$nbAmount$txtNumber:{required: 'Amount is required', number: 'Amount must be a valid number'},
                    ctl00$Content$dbPeriodicityStart$txtDate:{dateISO: 'Date must be ISO'},
                    ctl00$Content$dbPeriodicityStop$txtDate:{dateISO: 'Date must be ISO'},
                    ctl00$Content$ccTurnoverCategory$txtCategory:{required: 'Category is required'}

                }, 

                errorClass: "validationError", validClass: "validationValid",

        });
```

This all works fine on page load, the errors appears nicely in my error container defined like this at the top of the page:

```
            <div class="error-container">
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The problems start after i do a post back on my page (some controls has server events connected to them), then the post back is complete no errors renders in my errorLabelContainer but my validationError-class still works (red frame around inputs).

I tried to put my validation code in document.ready and in the pageLoad function, no success.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems like if i put my errorcontainer outside of my update panel it works like expected.